# 8 Thumbnail images linking to 8 different galleries, but only programmed once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage with 8 thumbnail images on it:

[image]

Each thumbnail as shown is a different kitchen. I want to be able to click on each thumbnail and enter a gallery of 4 closeups of that kitchen. I could obviously create 8 different web pages with their individual galleries on it, but in this modern era of web programming im sure there is a more efficient way of just creating one page whos content is dependent on which thumbnail was clicked?

My issue is im new to JavaScript and so cant think of how to implement this, and I know that  variables cant be passed from one html page to another as its just a markup language! Maybe the whole thing could be programmed in this one webpage with a 'pop-up' window (not one of those annoying pop up windows but more one of those cool looking transparent 'overlay' pop-ups!) as this would easily be able to know which image was clicked. Any ideas out there??

Comment: Your instinct is correct.  You can do this on a single page.  Unfortunately this question is not far enough along for a good answer.  There are any number of ways to do this (including probably thousands of photo gallery applications).  Pick an approach; try it out; ask questions when you run into specific problems.

Comment: @MikeBrant I agree with your sentiments and I have tried out a couple of JQuery based galleries, I suppose my main stumbling block is the 'overlay' window - a hint in the right direction for looking into this would be very much appreciated (i don't even know what they're technically called so i'm finding it hard to find any literature on it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of "Lightbox" type javascript/jquery applications you can try or any number of  photo galleries.

Here are a few that I've used in the past:

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

http://fancybox.net/

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: This is what I was looking for, very good links, very good answer. Thankyou (and now I know their called lightboxes!)